# How to solve "xxxx is not a function. (in...)" in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to create a custom `TabBar` component in React Native using Stateless components.

I'm using React Navigation v5.

I'm following [this](https://dev.to/hrastnik/lets-create-a-custom-animated-tab-bar-with-react-native-3496) source link, I copied the code as it is, but I'm getting `getAccessibilityLabel` is not a function.

Here

```
const TabBar = props => {
const {
  renderIcon,
  activeTintColor,
  inactiveTintColor,
  onTabPress,
  onTabLongPress,
  getAccessibilityLabel,
  navigation
 } = props;
 //...
 }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like the example is on v4 better follow the official docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/handling-safe-area/#hiddencustom-header-or-tab-bar

Comment: Is there a way to reproduce this same TabBar component in react navigation v5 ? I can't find anything about tab press or renderIcon for v5

Comment: You can use https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbaricon and https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbarbutton for that go through the docs :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I figured it out.